# Objective-C Parse Html Table Content

Tags: iphone, objective-c, parsing, uitableview, nsurlconnection

I'm looking for detailed instructions how to parse an html table content into UITableView.

I have the data from the `NSURLConnection` but I need specific part of the table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may use one of the DOM XML parsers, like [GData](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/), [KissXML](https://github.com/robbiehanson/KissXML) or [TouchXML](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML) + 
XPath API (all 3 seems to support it) to extract your data.

Comment: Is there any way to parse jquery mobile content to uitableview instead of your given xml parsers ?